# OAuth Google API Google Classroom

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-oauth, google-classroom

Hi I am trying to run the sample Quickstart code inorder to use the google classroom API. It seems the HTTP batch in the code is starting a server on a random port. When I tried to run the code, it opens my browser for authentication. But there is a 404 message saying that the redirect URI is not that of authorised client. If the port number keeps changing, how can I add a particular authorised client in my Developer Console for the credentials?

Comment: you need to fix your IDE so that it stops adding random ports.   The redirect URI must exactly match where you are sending it from in Google developers console.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Dalm I fixed by creating a LocalServerReceiver.Builder and setting the port.